# Can't extend abstract PHP class

Tags: php, class, oop, exception, extends

I want a base class to be extended, but I have some errors coming out:

> Fatal error: Class 'Api\Services\Base' not found in
>   /var/www/html/Api/Services/Example.php on line 7

I searched for typos, tried to use the fully qualified name, made the abstract class empty or just defined it as a simple class; none of these helped.
Using *"require"* instead of *"use"* worked, but still...

Any idea (the two files are in the same directory: */var/www/html/Api/Services*)?

Thanks in advance...

```
<?php
    // Base.php
    namespace Api\Services;

    use Api\Classes\ErrorHandler;
    use Api\Classes\ErrorMessage;

    abstract class Base
    {
        public $data = null;

        public function getData()
        {
            return $this->data;
        }

        public function setData($data = null)
        {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    // Example.php
    namespace Api\Services;

    use Api\Services\Base;

    class Example extends Base
    {
        public $request = array();

        public function __construct($request = array())
        {
            $this->request = $request;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: At witch point is the `autoloader` set up? And you dont need `use Api\Services\Base;` because you are in the same namespace `Api\Services`.

Comment: Note "require" works not like "use". *require* loads a FILE for real, `use` defines only the full namespaced name of a class. Did you know what this does: `use Api\Services\Base as MyBase;` ??

Comment: There is no autoloader. Maybe that is the problem (I'm new to OOP/PHP)?

Comment: Thats the bug. Read here http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ and http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/ and create one.

Comment: Or just include the file with `include_once('Base.php')` in `Example.php` after the `use` line. Than it works without an autoloader. But i thing you should read about Namespaces & Classes & Autoloading a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: It's working now, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
use Base
```

instead of

```
 use Api\Services\Base;
```

because you are already inside the namespace Api\Services

Actually, you don't even have to write the use statement, you are inside the namespace, you can just call the classes inside the same namespace without including them (`use`)

Comment: He is in the same namespace `Api\Services`, not need for `use` !